# SQL Server Active Directory Import Issues with British Summer Time (BST)

Tags: sql-server, datetime, active-directory

I'm using SQL Server ADSI to import data from Active Directory and using the whenChanged field to control if I need to reimport the members of a group.

Problem is the date is being returned in GMT and I'm currently in BST.

So, did a member change at 9:50 this morning, the AD tools I have say 9:50, but the ADSI query returns 8:50.  This means if there are two changes within an hour I will miss one.

The query I am using looks like this:

```
Select distinguishedName, whenChanged 
From OpenQuery(ADSI, '<LDAP://OU=Groups,DC=mydomain,DC=adr>;(objectCategory=Group);distingusihedName, whenChanged')
```

Is there another field I could use that would give me an accurate date?  Is there a better way to do what I am trying to do in SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you storing local time in the first place? The `whenChanged` property already gives you GMT, no hours can be "lost" in that time zone.

Its okay to convert to local time for display purposes, but I would definitely store GMT/UTC in the DB.

Comment: I had just come to the same conclussion, store the whenChanged as the last synced date and compare from that.  Thanks.